# What's the matter with the if/elif/else statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

The problem to this code is the syntax error for if/elif/else. But I don't know why it showed me the error.

```
try:
    if ans_three = '+':
        x = add(ans_one,ans_two)
        print("[+] Your Total Number: " + x)
    elif ans_three = '-':
        x = minus(ans_one, ans_two)
        print("[-] Your Total Number: " + x)
    elif ans_three = '*':
        x = minus(ans_one, ans_two)
        print("[*] Your Total Number: " + x)
    elif ans_three = '/':
        x = minus(ans_one, ans_two)
        print("[/] Your Total Number: " + x)
    else:
        print('>> Wrong operators! [+] [-] [*] [/]')
except ValueError:
    print("Invalid Number!")
    StopIteration
```

Here is the error:

```
if ans_three = '+':
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Process finished with exit code 1
```

The software I used is:

**PyCharm Community Edition 2017.1.3**

Comment: you should use `==` instead of `=`

Comment: More explicity, `==` tests equality, while `=` is for assignment.

Comment: SO specifically asks to avoid using comments to answer; please put some effort into writing an actual answer that can be accepted so the question can be marked as resolved @Sraw

Comment: thanks! I did not know that and I am new here. I did not expect to be that fast!

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig This question is too simple to be suitable for an answer, further, it is surly a duplicated question. That's why I didn't write an actual answer.

Comment: @Sraw simply flag it as such, then.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Yep, you are right. I'm still not very similar with this website.